# nor able to select file in android file manager using kivymd

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

**This is my kivymd code to open an android file manager if i select the file it is not showing in file selected please help me...**

1. I want to replace the MDFileManager instead of that i wanted to use android file manager
2. i am able to open the file manager when i select on the file its not selected

And also given permission in buldozer.spec file

```
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
    from kivy.app import App

    KV = '''
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Button:
            text: "Open File Manager"
            on_release: app.open_file_manager()

        Label:
            id: file_label
            text: "Selected File: None"
            halign: 'center'

        ScrollView:
            Label:
                id: file_content_label
                text: ""
'''

    class FileManagerApp(App):
        file_label = ObjectProperty()
        file_content_label = ObjectProperty()

        def build(self):
            return Builder.load_string(KV)

        def open_file_manager(self):
            from jnius import autoclass
            PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
            Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
            activity = PythonActivity.mActivity

            intent = Intent()
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
            intent.setType("*/*")

            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0)

        def on_activity_result(self, requestCode, resultCode, data):
            if resultCode == -1:  # Activity.RESULT_OK
                uri = data.getData()
                selected_file_name = self.get_file_name_from_uri(uri)
                self.root.ids.file_label.text = f"Selected File: {selected_file_name}"

                try:
                    with open(uri.getPath(), 'rb') as file:
                        raw_data = file.read()
                        file_content = raw_data.decode('utf-8')
                        self.file_content_label.text = file_content
                except Exception as e:
                    self.root.ids.file_content_label.text = f"Error reading file: {e}"

        def get_file_name_from_uri(self, uri):
            resolver = autoclass('android.content.ContentResolver')
            resolver_instance = resolver(activity.getContentResolver())
            cursor = resolver_instance.query(uri, None, None, None, None)
            if cursor.moveToFirst():
                column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex('_display_name')
                return cursor.getString(column_index)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        FileManagerApp().run()
```

[while debugging in android studio i am getting this error]
[this is the error i am getting in android studio log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWAYS.png)